# Exposing content of vars with SQL injection when handling exceptions

Tags: php

If I have this piece of code:

`query.php:`

```
$secret = 'This should not be displayed';
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
try {
  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = '$id'");
  }

catch(Exception $e) {
  echo "Could not execute" . "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_ID = '$id'";
}
```

$id is properly escaped, so no one can inject any code to my query, however, I'm wondering if I GET `query.php?id=$secret` will it echo the contents of the `$secret` var because of the echo in the exception handling part?

Comment: @Uriel_SVK - I'm at work and was very curious about it, but cannot try it out until I get back home ;)

Comment: No, I cant see anything there that would echo $secret. Id use mysqli or PDO to be safe though

Comment: Well, then you dont have to be afraid, it wont work. There is no way haw attacker could echo `$secret`

Answer (score 0):

You are safe with that operation ;)

If your `$id` is integer put `(int)$id` or `$id + 0`, etc...

good luck!